# Jquery append or jQuery create element.html?

Tags: jquery

I need to repeated large section (Account details section- Please see demo) when user click on add. What is the easy and best way to add/remove dynamically the whole section? 
Note. When user submits, I should be able to validate and capture the data so each field must be unique.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tK4f6/10/)

HTML:

```
 <button type="button" id="AddCC" class="btn btn-warning form-control">Add Another Card</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#AddCC').bind('click', function() {
        alert("Add clicked");

    $("#CCPanel").clone().appendTo("#container");

   });
```

Actually Clone is working perfect. I just placed id in wrong div tag before. Now my question is how to make fileds unique for validating and submiting ? Please see updated demo.

Comment: Perhaps you should look `clone()` also in your case, and simply add class to cloned form to refernce the new input fields :)

Comment: is ther a method called clone ?:)

Comment: Here it is  [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) .

Comment: Yes there ia clone() method but suggested not to use as it can create duplicate id's. In my case I need to hav ethose id's unique.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-add-remove-textbox-dynamically-with-jquery/ -- May work but too much complexity.

Comment: Note: Using .clone() has the side-effect of producing elements with duplicate id attributes, which are supposed to be unique. Where possible, it is recommended to avoid cloning elements with this attribute or using class attributes as identifiers instead.

Comment: Well i suggested clone() cause in your demo you do NOT use any id and as stated above you could clone the form and then `addClass()` to that form which will make it possible to reference it as a different form.

Comment: I din't quite understod wha tyou mean by adding a form. I think I need to repeat the whole section starting from "<div class="panel panel-primary">" and have all elemnts unique.

Comment: Can you please give me some sample for "add class to cloned form to refernce the new input fields "

Comment: After your user submits the forms what language you use to store the data? PHP? jquery?

Comment: I will submit to a servelet using jquery form submit

Comment: Ihave updated my post and Fiddler. I can see alert but clone is not working.

Comment: I also tried $("#CCcontainer").append($("#CCPanel").clone());, but no luck yet.

Comment: This is an example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2QJFV/)

Comment: Actually Clone is working perfect. I just placed id in wrong div tag before. Now my question is how to make fileds unique for validating and submiting ? Pleas esee updated demo.

Comment: Did you had a chnace to check my latest fiddle ? I just want to add a section of it not whole form. All I need now is how to make field id's unique. Aftre Clone, Can I update id's ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT :** this should be working.

Ok here is an example :

The Html:

```
<form action="">
    input1 :<input  type="text">
    input2 :<input  type="text">
</form>

    <input type="button" id="add" value="Add">
```

The jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add').click(function() {
        var firstForm = $('form').first().clone();
        $('form').first().after(firstForm) ; 
    });
});
```

If you want to target an input in the cloned form simply :

```
$(THE FORMS PARENT).find('form').eq(0).find('input').eq(1).val(); //---> eq(0)=1st form eq(1)=2nd  form... same thing with inputs as well
```

And the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uEZ5w/).

Comment: Finally when i cliked on payNow button, am i submiting multiple forms to server ?can we submit more than 1 form to server ?

Comment: Seems I crashed filddler when i try to run your demo. It want to loop when cliked add multiple times.

Comment: Edited my example excluding classes to make it simpler i am using the [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method. My demo seems to run fine.Let me know if my example helped you at all.

Comment: I am not sure how your demo is working. When i click add button first time, it addes two elements, then adding 10 elements then again going more than 30 or 50 elements ...why it is multiplying ? Also asi mnetioned, I cannot add entire form. I just need to clone only the section. I would appreciate ifyou ca ntake a look at my demo and see how to make fields unique.

Comment: At last sorry for my mistake, i have edited my answer above and updated my Fiddle.

Comment: I did below. How can i verify my elements have unique id ?var uniqueId = 1;
   $('#AddCC').click( function() {
    
    var copyDiv = $("#CCPanel").clone();
    var divID =  'CCPanel' + uniqueId;   
    copyDiv.attr('id',divID);
    
   $("#CCcontainer").append(copyDiv);
    
      $('#' + divID).find('input,select').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + uniqueId); 
             
         });
         uniqueId++;  
   
   });http://jsfiddle.net/tK4f6/11/

Comment: Never mind it is working perfect. I have solved problem myself. But Than kyou verymuch for your help.

Comment: Ok now it is working i hope i helped you even a little at least.

Comment: Yes are. You gave me basic idea and that is really important. Than kyou very much.  Ireally appreciate it. I have accepted your ansewer as it will be useful for me in future anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my final demo. Problem solved. http://jsfiddle.net/tK4f6/12/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 var uniqueId = 1;
$('#AddCC').click( function() {

var copyDiv = $("#CCPanel").clone();
var divID =  'CCPanel' + uniqueId;      
copyDiv.attr('id',divID);

 $("#CCcontainer").append(copyDiv);

     $('#' + divID).find('input,select').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + uniqueId); 

     });
     uniqueId++;  

 });
```